# adding custom header language does not reach server

Tags: django

I am on django 1.11 and from front-end, I want to pass a language header. I already am passing Authorization Bearer header parameter successfully but want to add a custom language header as well. Following [this](https://juristr.com/blog/2017/08/intercept-http-requests-in-angular/), I tried the following in my http interceptor:

```
  var lang=localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'en'; //WORKS
  req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('language',lang) }) //FAILS
```

When I say fails, I meant that the request OPTIONS is sent but it doesn't move on to GET method. My front-end is angular 6 if it matters.

Any idea?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you first perform an OPTIONS request here? It looks rather strange to not directly perform a GET.

Comment: Actually, I don't directly send OPTIONS request. I send GET/POST only from my Angular 6 app but I do see OPTIONS request going first before either methods tho I never explicitly specify an OPTIONS request (an MDN article did describe why OPTIONS request is first made by the browser so I guess it is ok).